# SqlAlchemy - Fails to establish remote connection, connects to (nonexistant) local server instead

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm having a big issue come up with Python (3.4) SqlAlchemy as of late, with a project that very much depends on this.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

Which is preceded with the following error:

```
  File "/home/dev/venv/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/queue.py", line 145, in get
raise Empty
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty
```

I have literally no idea why this issue is happening, and it's becoming quite the burden. If I connect with a SQLLite database, it works.

Here's the base string I'm using for connection:

```
mysql:///username:password@redacted:3306/inventory
```

*Credentials removed.*

The database configuration is loaded from a YAML file on disk, and is verified to be as expected.

All unit tests surrounding the connection have passed, though I only test with SQLLite.

Here is the code that's used to connect & create the database and its elements:

```
        self.database_config = {
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': self.config['databases']['source']['url'],
        # 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS': {
        #     'discard': self.config['databases']['discarded-items']['url']
        # }
    }

    try:
        db.init(config=self.database_config, Model=Model)
        # todo check if db exists
        logger.debug("Database Initialized!")
        db.create_all()
        logger.debug("Database Created")
        return True
    except SQLAlchemyError as ex:
        logger.error(ex)
        logger.info("Application config: {0}\nConfig Location: {1}\nDatabase Config: {2}".format(self.config,
                                                                                                 self.config_location,
                                                                                                 self.database_config))
        raise ex
```

Please, if I'm able to get any help that would be great! It's been quite the headache and would really like to resolve this!

Comment: What is your `db` object/where is it defined?  What does its `init` method do with the `config` parameter?  How/where is [`sqlalchemy.create_engine()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) being invoked?

Comment: Is that locally with your mysql? If not you need to grant with the address you are connecting from to mysql.

Comment: @eggyal The DB Object is a SQLAlchemy manager, named "Alchy" which allows flask-sqlalchemy like invocation of sqlalchemy outside of that framework & environment. The engine is being created when I pass the configuration, as you see.

The init method is like a late-bind, allowing me to create the component and then initialize it when the application instance is generated.

Comment: @giaosudau I'm attempting to do this now. Thanks.

Comment: According to its [API Reference](https://alchy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#alchy.manager.Manager) and [source](https://alchy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/alchy/manager.html#Manager), `alchy.manager.Manager` does not have a method named `init` (and you can't invoke `__init__` if you omit the underscores).  Did you mean to pass those arguments to the constructor e.g. `db = Manager(config=self.database_config, Model=Model)`, or perhaps call `__init__` explicitly e.g. `db.__init__(config=self.database_config, Model=Model)`?

Comment: @eggyal I understand what you're saying. When I discovered Alchy I created a fork, and actually submitted a pull request to add late-binding to the application.

https://github.com/dgilland/alchy/pull/31

This is a very small change, and during tests it held up. Thanks for the help; Hopefully I can sort this soon.

Comment: Oh, I'm being blind.  You have one too many slashes in the DSN.  It should be `mysql://username:password@redacted:3306/inventory` not `mysql:///`.

Comment: Well, that's rather awkward. Thanks for this!